# How to start another application(pod) from a CRON JOB

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-cronjob

I have a CRON JOB in Azure k8s which trigger once a day, based on the condition written inside of this CRON JOB (image), I need to start another application/s(Pods) which will do some process and dies

Answer (score 1):

I'll describe a solution that requires running `kubectl` commands from within the `CronJob` Pod. If the image you're using to create the `CronJob` doesn't have the `kubectl` command, you'll need to install it.
In short, you can use a Bash script that creates Deployment (or Pod) and then you can mount that script in a volume to the `CronJob` Pod.

Below, I will provide a detailed step-by-step explanation.

---

This is a really simple bash script that we'll mount to the `CronJob` Pod:
**NOTE:** You may need to modify this script as needed. If the image you're using to create the `CronJob` doesn't have the `kubectl` command installed, you can install it in this script.

```
$ cat deploy-script.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Creaing 'web-app'"
kubectl create deployment web-app --image=nginx
sleep 10
echo "Deleting 'web-app'"
kubectl delete deployment web-app
```

We want to run this script from inside the Pod, so I converted it to `ConfigMap` which will allow us to mount this script in a volume (see: [Using ConfigMaps as files from a Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#using-configmaps-as-files-from-a-pod)):

```
$ cat deploy-script-configmap.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: deploy-script
data:
  deployScript.sh: |
    #!/bin/bash

    echo "Creaing 'web-app'"
    kubectl create deployment web-app --image=nginx
    sleep 10
    echo "Deleting 'web-app'"
    kubectl delete deployment web-app

$ kubectl apply -f deploy-script-configmap.yml
configmap/deploy-script created
```

Then I created a separate `cron-user` ServiceAccount with the `edit` Role assigned and our `CronJob` will run under this ServiceAccount:

```
$ cat cron-job.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: cron-user
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: cron-user-binding
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: cron-user
    namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: edit
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: deploy-cron-job
spec:
  schedule: "*/2 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: cron-user
          volumes:
            - name: deploy-script
              configMap:
                name: deploy-script
          containers:
          - name: cron-job-1
            image: bitnami/kubectl
            command: ["bash", "/mnt/deployScript.sh"]
            volumeMounts:
            - name: deploy-script
              mountPath: /mnt/
```

After applying the above manifest, the `deploy-cron-job` CronJob was created:

```
$ kubectl apply -f cron-job.yaml
serviceaccount/cron-user created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/cron-user-binding created
cronjob.batch/deploy-cron-job created

$ kubectl get cronjob
NAME              SCHEDULE      SUSPEND   ACTIVE   
deploy-cron-job   */2 * * * *   False     1
```

After a while, the `CronJob` Pod was created and as we can see from the logs, it created a `web-app` Deployment as expected:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                       READY   STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
deploy-cron-job-1626426840-6w6s9           0/1     Completed     0          21s

$ kubectl logs -f deploy-cron-job-1626426840-6w6s9
Creaing 'web-app'
deployment.apps/web-app created
Deleting 'web-app'
deployment.apps "web-app" deleted
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create two cron pods run **on the same time** you need to create **two  cron jobs** , but if you need the two jobs run on d**ifferent time** so you can **use the same cron jobs that run twice per day** you can schedule so you cron jobs like that:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "* */12 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

This will be run every 12 hours .

Comment: seems I confused you, the requirement is to start another different application only if  some condition satisfies written inside the CRON JOB  (in simpler terms how to invoke /start a POD which is another application from this CRON JOB  POD)

Comment: as you can see inside the cron job template you have containers , so you can add one or multiple containers so instead create multiple pods you can use multiple containers that can be handled when a condition verified an died after termination this will be better .