# Kubernetes Istio Envoy - Rate Limiting by HTTP Method

Tags: kubernetes, istio, rate-limiting

We are using Istio Envoy based Rate limiting (with Kubernetes & Docker) as specified in [this documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limit/).

Although I was able to set it up for local and global rate limiting in the Kubernetes cluster, I am unable to achieve the following:

1. Rate limit a Service only for POST requests, while GET requests should go through unencumbered.
2. Rate limit a Service only for a certain time duration (e.g. 9 AM to 5 PM EST) and work normally at other times.

Is the above possible in current Istio functionalities?

Comment: What exactly did you do? What exactly do you want to achive and how? Please paste your yaml files.

Comment: I followed the guidelines mentioned in the link posted above.  But the document does not mention if HTTP method based filter is possible.

Comment: You told "I am unable to achieve the following..." - So what exactly did you try to achieve this?

Comment: I did not find any info that would enable the aforementioned functionality.  I want to check with the community if this is even feasible and supported by Envoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer both of your questions below.

##### 1. Rate limit a Service only for a specific request method

We can use the [header_value_match](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.14.5/api-v2/api/v2/route/route_components.proto#envoy-api-msg-route-ratelimit-action-headervaluematch) rate limit actions.

I created a single `rate_limits filter` with one `action` that matches any request with method **GET**:
**NOTE:** For the sake of simplicity, I have only given an important part of the configuration.

Envoy rate_limits filter configuration:

```
...
        value:
          rate_limits:
            - actions:
              - header_value_match:
                  descriptor_value: get
                  headers:
                  - name: :method
                    prefix_match: GET
...
```

Next, I created a `ratelimit service configuration` that matches descriptors with key `header_match` and value `get`. It will provide a limit of 1 request per minute:

```
...
    descriptors:
      - key: header_match
        rate_limit:
          unit: minute
          requests_per_unit: 1
        value: get
...
```

After applying the above configuration, we can check whether it will be possible to use the **GET** method more than once within 1 minute:

```
$ curl "http://$GATEWAY_URL/productpage" -I -X GET
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
content-length: 5179
server: istio-envoy
date: Tue, 11 Jan 2022 09:57:33 GMT
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 120


$ curl "http://$GATEWAY_URL/productpage" -I -X GET
HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests
x-envoy-ratelimited: true
date: Tue, 11 Jan 2022 09:57:35 GMT
server: istio-envoy
content-length: 0
```

As we can see, after the second request, we received the HTTP [429 Too Many Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) response status code which indicates that the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time. It means that everything works as expected.

I recommend you to read the [Understanding Envoy Rate Limits](https://www.aboutwayfair.com/tech-innovation/understanding-envoy-rate-limits) article which contains a lot of useful information.

##### 2. Rate limit a Service only for a certain time duration (e.g. 9 AM to 5 PM EST) and work normally at other times.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any suitable option to configure this behavior. I think that [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) can be used as a workaround, which will run periodically on a given schedule and will create/delete the appropriate configuration responsible for rate-limiting. In short, you can use a Bash script that creates/deletes a configuration responsible for rate-limiting and then you can mount that script in a volume to the `CronJob` Pod.
I have already described a similar use of `CronJob` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68406717/14801225) and believe it can help you.

Comment: Appreciate your response @matt_j.  Can the configuration for 1st point be applicable to a Single service (aka, not global)?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like to configure the same but for one service. In that case, it is also known as a global rate limit. Unfortunately, I've never configured it that way, but I think the second example in this [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/) might help you.
Global rate limit relies on a separate service to enforce the limits. Local rate limit works per each instance of envoy. They are distinct use cases.

Comment: Oh. Is it?  I completely misunderstood it then.  What I thought was:  Global Rate Limit applies to the entire K8S cluster, while Local Rate Limit only applies to a Single K8S Deployment.  Is this not the case?

Comment: Local rate limiting is used to limit the rate of requests per service instance. This allows you to apply rate limits at the instance level, in the proxy itself, without calling any other service. It is possible to use local rate limit with HTTP headers. However, it would require portioning the limits per each instance/route instead of having one global limit.

Comment: Hi, will you please post sample manifest file here for applying rate limits on a particular service and a specific API path.